# PowerApps canvas app - safari browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have created a PowerApps form (canvas) embedded in SharePoint and publish that. It is working fine in desktop but when I open the same link in iPhone (safari or chrome). I get this message.

> A missing cookie prevented sign in for one of your services. To avoid
> signing in for each additional service, make sure third-party cookies
> are allowed in your browser. For Safari, disable "Prevent Cross-Site
> Tracking" in the "Privacy and Security" section of settings

I don’t want to change settings in iPhone as there are many users and we can’t ask end users to change their iPhone settings for using power app.

Any solution?[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to the forum dedicated to PowerApps for more help:

[Microsoft Power Apps Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1)